# Use firebase-functions for firebase v2 cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How can I write these functions such that there work with v2.

```
const {onSchedule} = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler");
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const {functions} = require("firebase-functions");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const firebaseTools = require("firebase-tools");

initializeApp();

async function deletePath(path) {
  await firebaseTools.firestore
      .delete(path, {
        project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
        recursive: true,
        force: true,
        token: functions.config().fb.token,
      });
}
```

The cloud console is giving me this error:

> Error: functions.config() is no longer available in Cloud Functions for Firebase v2.  Please see the latest documentation for information on how to transition to using environment variables

I have checked the documentation. There are some examples with `onDocumentCreated`. I could figure out how that could help me.

Comment: You're supposed to replace the use of the old `functions.config()` with environment variables from the documentation you read.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson, that is exactly what I can't figure out.

Comment: What part of that are you struggling with?  All you're doing is changing the source of data and how you get a hold of it in the function.  You should give it a try, then post the specifics of what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Doug Stevenson:

> You're supposed to replace the use of the old functions.config() with environment variables from the documentation you read.
> **Use environment variables to access configuration values**

```
const fbToken = process.env.FB_TOKEN; // Configure this as a variable in the environment

async function deletePath(path) {
  await firebaseTools.firestore
    .delete(path, {
      project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
      recursive: true,
      force: true,
      token: fbToken,
    });
}
```

Then

Use `firebase deploy --only functions` to deploy v2 functions.

Reference:

- [Configure your environment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#env-variables)
- [V2 and examples: Extend Cloud Firestore with Cloud Functions (2nd gen)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions-2nd-gen)